# How can I update a django BooleanField with a logical combination of other BooleanField's on the same model?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

Consider this simple django model (backed by Postgres):

```
class M(Model):
    a = BooleanField(default=False)
    b = BooleanField(default=False)
    c = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app'
```

How can I use `update` to set the value of `c` to the logical AND of `a` and `b`?  My first instinct was

```
M.objects.update(c=F('a') and F('b'))
```

but apparently the python is executed first (with the logical AND of the `F` functions simply returning the second method), because this yields the following SQL:

```
UPDATE "my_app_m"
SET "c" = "my_app_m"."b"
```

I tried wrapping the expression in `ExpressionWrapper`, but this had no effect.  I also tried using `*` instead of `and` (to multiply the F expressions), but this yielded an operation error on the sql side.

I know I could do this in python by fetching the objects, manipulating them, and then saving.  I'm guessing I could also probably do the update by casting to int then multiplying, then casting back.  But I'm surprised the ORM doesn't simply handle this.  Is there a step I'm missing, or a different standard way of accomplishing the same effect?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

After poking around a bit, I found this solution.  Not a huge fan of answering my own questions, but this was vexing me so maybe it will help someone else.  I'm not sure if it's the best or most direct solution, so hopefully someone else will come up with a better answer and I can accept that.

What I have right now:

```
    M.objects.update(
        c=Case(
            When(a=True, b=True, then=Value(True)),
            default=Value(False)
        )
    )
```

Another alternative.  Guess this should have been obvious given the nature of this specific problem, but it never occurs to me to opt for more queries:

```
    M.objects.update(c=False)
    M.objects.filter(a=True, b=True).update(c=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `Q` object here:

```
from django.db.models import Q

M.objects.update(c=Q(a=True, b=True))
```

In PostgreSQL, this will result in a query:

```
UPDATE "my_app_m"
SET "c" = ("my_app_m"."a" = true AND "my_app_m"."b" = true)
```

Comment: That looks much better.  My first attempt yielded a validation error (logical and of objects that look like "<django.db.models.lookups.Exact object at 0x10bc24550>"), though.  Will poke around a bit more at this

Comment: If we don't want to ***store the results into the DB***, we could use **`c`** as a **`property()`**

Comment: @JPG: yes, but it is not said that we always want to set `c` to `a and b`, or for all `M`s. It is also possible that `c` is an independent column, that is updated for some records that way, but can later change for example.